# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure in JDK1.8.0_71 but not in JDK1.8.0_162

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

Below code works fine with JDK1.8.0_162 but in JDK 1.8.0_71 its throwing

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

```
SSLSocketFactory factory =
                (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            System.out.println("before create socket.........................");
            SSLSocket socket =
                (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("creditbureaureports.com", 443);

            System.out.println("after create socket.........................");
            socket.startHandshake();
            System.out.println("After start handshake...........");
```

Changing the URL to google.com in 1.8.0_71 , results in different error "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" which is fine, as it looking for valid certification.

So question is why i'm getting ssl_handshake error for creditbureaureports.com in 1.8.0_71 but not in JDK 1.8.0_162?

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of Java 8? Both Java 8 update 71 and Java 8 update 162 are pretty old. But if you want to know, I'd recommend scanning the release notes of all versions between update 71 and 162. The difference is probably the addition of new root certificates in the cacerts keystore between those two versions, and the server you're connecting has a SSL certificate signed using one of those new root CA certificates.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel There might also be some SSL protocols or cipher suites available in 1.8.0_162 that are not available in 1.8.0_71.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That is also possible, I know there were a lot of SSL/TLS support changes between versions.

Comment: I can understand there could be difference in cacert, how to check what exactly is causing the issue?

Comment: Just upgrade Java to a recent version, eg Java 8 update 232. You are using old and insecure versions, which is a risk for your company or clients. Why do you care to identify the specific problem, when the solution is to upgrade.

Comment: You can try `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to get a verbose output and then analyse it.